# using slug function in button but button below div code are hide

Tags: php, .htaccess

i using slug in a button then my button div below code automatic hide in page..
using in function page
this my function.php

```
   function php_slug($string)  
 {  
      $slug = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9-]+/', '-', trim(strtolower($string)));  
      return $slug;  
 }
```

using in .htaccess page

```
RewriteEngine On

#RewriteRule ^package/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ package-details.php?package_url=$1  
#RewriteRule ^package/([a-zA-Z-0-9-]+)/ package-details.php?package_url=$1
```

using in a buttom tag
this is my index.php
in index.php link function.php

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="package/<?php echo php_slug($title);  ?>">View Details</a>
```

without slug my page like

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ih934.png)

Comment: Welcome, what is your question?

Comment: i want to change url like SEO friendly in php and i want click a button then redirect to another page then url show here SEO friendly

Comment: Ok, now that we know what you want, please tell us what you have! Something not working? Problems with your slug not being generated? Wrong slug generated? Where exactly do you redirect in your code? Button not working? (On a sidenote, having two _commented_ RewriteRules will lead you nowhere)

Comment: slug successfully generate but slug function echo in anchor tag url such like :- <a class="btn btn-primary" href="package/<?php echo (php_slug($title));  ?>">View Details</a>  but all div hide of anchor tag div below

Comment: all div hide below of anchor tag

Comment: please see attach image

Comment: problem solve that but redirect page CSS not work